# How to apply mapping functions using furrr on tidygraph objects?

Tags: r, purrr, tidygraph, r-future, furrr

The parallel calculations on tidygraph centrality functions using furrr is throwing an error:

> "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: This
> function should not be called directly."

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)
library(furrr)

H <- play_islands(5, 10, 0.8, 3)

cent <- tribble(
  ~f,      ~params,                  
  "centrality_degree", list(H),  
  "centrality_authority", list(H)  
)

cent %>% 
  mutate(centrality = future_invoke_map(f, params, .options = future_options(packages = c("tidygraph", "tidyverse"))))
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Do you need `cent %>% mutate(out = future_map2(params, f, ~ .x %>% extract2(1) %>% mutate(out = .y)))`

Comment: How should I extract 'out' variable so that I can read it like a plain vanilla dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a misunderstanding about how the tidygraph works, which prevents you from coding this correctly.

The functions `centrality_degree()` and `centrality_authority()` are both used within a `mutate()` statement (see https://tidygraph.data-imaginist.com/reference/centrality.html).

```r
library(tidygraph)
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
create_notable('bull') %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  mutate(importance = centrality_authority())
#> # A tbl_graph: 5 nodes and 5 edges
#> #
#> # An undirected simple graph with 1 component
#> #
#> # Node Data: 5 x 1 (active)
#>   importance
#>        <dbl>
#> 1      0.869
#> 2      1    
#> 3      1    
#> 4      0.434
#> 5      0.434
#> #
#> # Edge Data: 5 x 2
#>    from    to
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     1     3
#> 3     2     3
#> # ... with 2 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that `centrality_authority()` function within the `mutate()` statement. In other words, you'll need to wrap these functions around another function to pass to the `furrr` functions.

Also, note that the result of the proper use of these functions return a `tidygraph` object. There is a function [`graph_join()`](https://tidygraph.data-imaginist.com/reference/graph_join.html) that allows us to join multiple graphs together. So a plan similar to the one you have proposed is to calculate separate centrality measures, which each return a graph object, and then to join them together with `graph_join()`.

With this knowledge, we can code this up as follows (note a minor change to your code where we have to add some unique ID name to the nodes so that we can join the graphs together).

```r
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(furrr)
#> Loading required package: future
 
# Create example graph
H <- play_islands(5, 10, 0.8, 3) %>%
  mutate(name = 1:50)  # Add node names to join
  
# Create functions to add centrality measures
f_c_deg <- function(x) x %>% mutate(c_deg = centrality_degree())
f_c_aut <- function(x) x %>% mutate(c_aut = centrality_authority())
  
# Setup mapping data frame
cent <- tribble(
  ~f,      ~params,                  
  "f_c_deg", list(x = H),
  "f_c_aut", list(x = H)
)
  
# Apply functions and join
res <- future_invoke_map(cent$f, cent$params)
one_g <- Reduce(graph_join, res)  # Put together results and view single graph
#> Joining, by = "name"

one_g
#> # A tbl_graph: 50 nodes and 416 edges
#> #
#> # A directed acyclic multigraph with 1 component
#> #
#> # Node Data: 50 x 3 (active)
#>    name c_deg c_aut
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     7 0.523
#> 2     2     9 0.661
#> 3     3     9 0.670
#> 4     4     8 0.601
#> 5     5     9 0.637
#> 6     6    11 0.823
#> # ... with 44 more rows
#> #
#> # Edge Data: 416 x 2
#>    from    to
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     1     3
#> 3     1     4
#> # ... with 413 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: wow...thanks @Eric!! Appreciate your detailed explanation!